# KQL query to only join tables with a column value

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

If my query is returning:

| Id | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Value |  |
| 123 |  | Value |
| 456 | Value |  |
| 456 |  | Value |

and I have a second query that returns:

| Id | Column3 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 50 |
| 456 | 75 |

How can I join the two querys by Id *without* the Column3 value appearing for every row where an Id is present - rather, for every row where it is present *AND* has a value only in Column1. For example:

| Id | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Value |  | 50 |
| 123 |  | Value |  |
| 456 | Value |  | 75 |
| 456 |  | Value |  |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate `Column3` using the `case()` function with the logic you've described.

For example:

```
let q1 = datatable(Id:long, Column1:string, Column2:string)
[
    123, 'Value', '',
    123, '', 'Value',
    456, 'Value', '',
    456, '', 'Value',
]
;
let q2 = datatable(Id:long, Column3:long)
[
    123, 50,
    456, 75,
]
;
q1
| join kind=inner q2 on Id
| project Id, Column1, Column2, Column3 = case(isempty(Column1), long(null), Column3)
```

| Id | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 |  | Value |  |
| 123 | Value |  | 50 |
| 456 |  | Value |  |
| 456 | Value |  | 75 |